# Using Modern Ie, trying to get windows 8.1 browser

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, installation, virtualbox

Using:
https://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

My OS: ubuntu 12.04, trying to install windows 8.1 internet explorer.

ERROR:
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine IE11 - Win8.1.
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).